# How to gives space to paragraph inside string value

Tags: android, string, android-studio, text

I have some text inside string of value folder in android studio and I want to give space between paragraph but I don't know how to do that ?

Comment: put \n after every paragraph. Result : Next word will start with new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use \n for new line and add space by entering space

for example:

```
<string name="above_eightteen">I confirm that \n I am above 18 years and agree to all Age restriction disclaimer.</string>
```

and use this string value in your layout.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your text will be a straight line in the string.xml file. find out the point where a paragraph is starting or ending, and put "\n" before paragraph start or after paragraph end.